# Inserting a html/css text copied with zeroclipboard to libre office document

Tags: html, css, libreoffice, zeroclipboard

I wonder how to insert a hmtl / css text copied with **zeroclipboard** to **libre office** document?
The zeroclipboard copies for example this:

```
<div class="viewentry">
    <a href="./edit.php">
      <span class="e1"> Adría··haf </span>
    </a>
    <span class="pos">n (-s)</span><br>
    <div class="main_entry">
        <span class="num">1)</span>
        <a href="./edit.phpe"></a>
        <a href="./edit.php">
          <span class="specification"> geog. </span>
          <span class="dtrn2"> Jaderské moře, Jadran </span>
        </a>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to insert this text formated into libre office document - formated as in html page (two lines, e1 class large etc.)
The solution would help us to correct dictionary quicker.

Comment: Can you not just manualy format it?

Comment: Yes, I can prepare different text with different formatting for the copied text.

Comment: So you want to copy the html into libreoffice and spellcheck it?

Comment: I want to paste that text into libreoffice and preserve (or simulate) the same formatting. If I can paste directly the html (with css) into libreoffice, that would ease it all.

Comment: Try "CTRL + SHIFT + V" Which is special paste